# Create Grouped Products programmatically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, magento

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

In my magento I have two types of account !) Buyer 2) Seller

I want to provide one option for the Sellers to add Grouped products

For this I don't have any ideas & i am very new to this technology

I am using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

For this what I have to do?

Comment: I tried to search in internet about this but no use ...

Comment: anyone have any ideas